# Is spawning new threads via a LINQ Select call bad code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, delegates, side-effects

ReSharper refactored a foreach loop I had to something like this.  I wanted to spawn a bunch of threads via a delegate's BeginInvoke with different parameters, stored in a list, and store the IAsyncResults in a collection:

```
var asyncResults = mylist.Select(x => myDelegate.BeginInvoke(x, null, null));
```

My instinctive reaction is that this is not a good practice. BeginInvoke is causing a side effect of a new thread being spawned, and functions passed to Select should not cause side effects.

Or maybe it's ok, because I'm not altering anything in the calling thread?

Comment: Before you ask yourself "is this a good practice?" ask yourself "does this code even implement the behaviour that I am describing?" It does not; this code merely creates a query object. You have created an object that means "I am the query that produces a sequence of async results from this list". *Being* that query does not cause the query to *execute*. If you want to execute the query and store the results in a collection, you're going to have to write more code.

Comment: It doesn't do anything on its own, but it could be appropriate in some situations.  However, when you call BeginInvoke I guess you generally want the threads to start then and there, so a LINQ query is quite different to a foreach loop in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's hard to tell whether this is a good practice or not, it depends on how are you using it.

But the important thing to remember when using LINQ like this is that `Select()` (and many other LINQ methods) doesn't actually iterate over the collection and execute your code. That happens only when you iterate over the resulting collection, usually using `foreach` or `ToArray()`.

Comment: Yeah, I think this could be appropriate only if you didn't mind not having full control over when exactly the threads were spawned.  I forgot about LINQ's laziness.

Answer (score 3):

That should be fine. Creating a new thread isn't really a side affect. You're not modifying any values. `BeginInvoke` is called and you're storing the resulting `IAsyncResult`s.

You will have to keep in mind, though, that nothing is going to block. You'll have to manage the synchronization of everything yourself.